# Route traffic of specific domain to different ip?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, webserver, redirection

I am working on a project where my customer wants to redirect traffic going out to, let's say, www.google.com, to a localhost web server on **Windows 10**.

So instead of configuring a dedicated server that monitors all traffic from other computers, she want's the traffic to be monitored and managed by the device itself due to potential offline situations.

In a normal scenario the user would browse for www.google.com and Google would appear.

In our scenario we want something else to appear instead.

So normal scenario would be: user > internet > www.google.com
In our scenario we want: user > redirection > internal HTTP server

I have thought about packet sniffing and packet replacement but that would be overkill.

A simple reconfiguration at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` or alike with additional tools would be the correct way to do it I guess?

Also, I think VPN would not fit this project due to offline scenarios.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The only way you can make something similar work for HTTPS is by setting up a proxy and it will ***not*** pretend to be the site you're trying to reach, which is immoral, possibly illegal, and very risky.

Comment: Pretend? What do you mean?

Comment: When google engages https automatically browser warnings will go off all over the place.  When using chrome your attempt to impersonate google will immediately be reported to google HQ, and it will prevent you from proceeding at all.  You need an SSL end point server of some kind.  You would have to prevent the users web browser from switching to https automatically.

Comment: Am I missing something or what? I'm going to quote myself here `In our scenario we want something else to appear instead.`.  And again `we want something else to appear instead`. and again `something else to appear instead`. We want to show our own website. when offline or online at specific situations. Hence the reason that `we want something else to appear instead.`

Comment: @vaid - no need to talk down to cybernard - Despite your protestations, cybernard email is still correct - regardless of whether googles site appears or your own, in order to make this work over SSL you still need to, in effect, perform a MITM attack on the traffic, which will throw up alerts unless you take appropriate steps to add your own root cert to her computer and self-sign the resulting page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to talk down on anyone, I just wanted to make it very clear to future visitors what I want to accomplish before this becomes a discussion about Google and trickery. So it is not possible to somehow catch any HTTP requests and redirect them while being offline? (at least)